# c++ mortgage calculator - term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I need to make a program to calculate monthly mortgage payment. The formula I was given is

> P = L[(r/12)(1+r/12)n]/[(1+r/12)n -1]

Where
P = the monthly payment
L = the loan amount
r = the interest rate
n = number of months of the life of the loan.

On line 37

```
p = l * (r / 12)(1 + (r / pow(12, n))) / (1 + r / pow(12, n)) - 1;
```

I keep getting an error that states:

```
Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-function type)  
Term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

How do I fix this?

This is my entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main() {


    double p = 0, l = 0, d = 0, c = 0, r = 0;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Welcome to the Mortgage Payment Calculator \n";

    cout << "Please enter the information \n";
    cout << "Cost of home: \n";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Loan amount: \n";
    cin >> l;
    cout << "Interest rate: \n";
    cin >> r;
    cout << "Number of months on loan: \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Downpayment: \n";
    cin >> d;


    cout << "Cost of home : " << c;
    cout << "Down Payment : " << d;
    cout << "Loan: " << c - d;
    cout << "Interest rate: " << r;
    cout << "Number of months for life of loan: " << n;
    cout << endl;

    //formula

    p = l * (r / 12)(1 + (r / pow(12, n))) / (1 + r / pow(12, n)) - 1;

    cout << "You owe the mortgage company: " << l - d;
    cout << "your monthly payment is: " << p << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This term here:

```
(r / 12)(1 + (r / pow(12, n)))
```

There is no implied multiplication here as with mathematics. You need to specify the multiplication `*`.

```
(r / 12) * (1 + (r / pow(12, n)))
        ^^^
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, thank you.

Comment: It's easy to do, especially when the error message (while completely correct for a compiler,) is not immediately clear.